# Как записать response, полученный от сервера в формате JSON в Java объект для последующего парсинга?

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

Я получаю JSON от внешнего rest api и мне нужно его распарсить, достать некоторые элементы и закинуть их в Map.
Для того, чтобы распарсить Json, нужно его правильно записать, если я правильно понял.
Код контроллера:

```
@Value("${weather.url}")
String url;
private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

public WeatherController(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
    this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
}
@GetMapping("/")
public ResponseEntity getWeather() {
    return restTemplate.getForEntity(url, String.class);
}
```

Буду благодарен любому совету!

Comment: restTemplate.getForEntity(url, String.class); - здесь вы получаете стринг, т.е. сырой джейсон. создайте класс с полями , соответсвующими джейсону, и вместо стринга подставляйте этот класс. джейсон автоматически спарсится в объект этого класса

Comment: @Дмитрий, я думал об этом, но там около 700 строк, поэтому хочу сохранить сырой джейсон спарсить его, достать оттуда что мне нужно, а затем закинуть информацию в БД.

Comment: если вам нужны выборочные поля, тогда 2 варианта: 1) создавайте класс только с теми полями, которые вам необходимы, остальные можно просто игнорировать; 2)парсите в map <String, Object>. по имени поля можете получить все, что нужно, а с помощью джексоновского меппера еще и смепить автоматически.